# Adding Function To Controllers Before Saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, controller

I am trying to figure out a good ("best", if possible) way to architect a solution in which I can do some work on a MVC model in the controller before committing changes back to the database using EF6.

So here is an example--I have this code in one of my controller classes:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]      
    public ActionResult Edit(Role role)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(role).State = EntityState.Modified;
    //***********---> HERE IS WHERE I WOULD PLACE THE PRE-SAVECHANGES CALL
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(role);
    }
```

As noted above, I want to call a "pre-savechanges" function right before db.SaveChanges(). The key is that I want to do this for all of my controllers and I would like the way in which this function is called to be the same in all of the controllers so that this pre-save implementation is consistent (in other words, the function name should be the same and it should take the model as an argument--I'm trying to avoid tying the name of the function to the model name in any way). For instance, the function could be called PreSaveChanges and it would need access to the model about to be persisted (role, in this case depicted in the code snipped above).

I understand there are many ways to achieve this but one way I thought about is to just add a function to each model--but I don't see examples of functions within models and I'm not experienced enough to understand the ramifications (such as the testability) of such an approach. I also thought about some sort of inversion-of-control/dependency injection solution, since that often seems to be a popular choice. Whatever the approach, I wouldn't want to require that the pre-savechanges function needs to actually exist. In other words, some controllers will have models that require pre-processing before being persisted, and others won't. I would still want all of my controllers to attempt to call the pre-savechanges function but if it hasn't been defined or doesn't exist then that's fine--then the dbSaveChanges() line should execute next.

So, going through some of the options quickly:

1. I have considered making a static function in a utility class that would take my model (in this case, warrantymodel) as an argument--but then I don't know whether the receiving function should accept a generic type or a object of type "object" type--both would require some reflection code so that I know what model has been passed. I would probably have a large 'if' block that would look at the type (if role, then do this; if user, then do this; etc.). The call in my controller would probably look something like this:

   ```
   Utility.PreSaveChanges(warrantymodel);
   ```

If you think this is the best approach, should PreSaveChanges have a parameter of type object or should it accept a generic type?

1. I also thought that I could put the pre-save function in the model itself. I like the idea of including the pre-save function code in the model, as I mentioned above, but I just don't know if that's a good idea. That code would look like this:

   ```
   warrantymodel.PreSaveChanges();
   ```

If you think this is the best approach, can you confirm that it's okay to have functions within the model? Does that break some sort of MVC tenet?

I have only scratched the surface of dependency injection--so I don't know if that would help here. If it will, I'd love to see a brief example (I've read enough about DI that I would understand it without too much explanation).

Comment: Your problem stems from the fact that your data object, business object and UI object are all the same thing. You need to use view models.

Comment: Yes, this was just a simple example from the controller logic that MVC scaffolds provide. I understand and agree that more models should be involved. I appreciate your constructive criticism but the thrust of this question had more to do with where to add pre-save logic, model architecture aside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only can there be functions in your model class, there should be if you are doing any work on that entity. Keep the behavior and logic for you model encapsulated inside of your model class where it belongs. NOT IN THE CONTROLLER EVER! Think FAT models, SKINNY Controllers.

Secondly, if you would like to implement the `PreSaveChanges` function on all of your models I would probably create an Interface like `IPreSaveFunctionality` that contains a `PreSaveChanges` method stub and have each model implement this interface that you want to be able to `PreSaveChanges`.

However if the logic is going to be the same for whatever model you pass it then I would create a `BaseModel` class and create a virtual method in that class and have all of your other models derive from `BaseModel` and if a few models have different implementations for this function then you can always override the implementation of `PreSaveChanges` for that individual model in that model class.

Comment: Nice to hear--I will keep the fat/skinny mantra in mind as I continue with MVC!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options:

1) As Ant P suggested, make a 'vanilla' model that would be different from your other models and that would be the model that you would bind to when you submit your action. Then it would be easy to create a utility method that accepts only this one type of model and works with it.

2) Another option, you can have all your models inherit from a 'vanilla' model and when you receive your 'special' model simply downcast that model to the vanilla one and send it to the utility method for processing.

Comment: See my comment to Ant P--I was really more concerned with where/how to extend the controller logic.